# Git check out leave folder locked ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu

every time i checkout a branch in git and come back to previous branch it leaves directory locked

I am typing in commad sudo chmod 777 -R foldername to unlock folder every time. I am having 3 branches what to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "locked"?

Comment: "sudo chmod 777 -R foldername": mode 777 seems like really bad practice.

Comment: do you have a file under .git/index.lock ?

Comment: have you created the folder with superuser permission?

Comment: @Evert what i meant by locked is that some  files in folder is not editable

Comment: @fortune no i have found no such file

Comment: @GauravPaliwal  yes my folder has super user permission .

Comment: @ShershaFn if you are in linux its a hidden file. You need to got to folder .git and run ls -la command

Comment: Are you running part of your (git) commands as a normal user, and part with `sudo`? You may be creating a simple user permission problem.

Comment: i am using sudo to checkout to change directory when i come back to original directory after a pull everything gets locked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the folder without sudo permission and then try to run commands you want to execute.